# Wi-Fi keeps on dying

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

Usually when I start the pc Wi-Fi is all good. Then after some trafic, some games or some Youtube for example the Wi-Fi simply doesn't give me trafic anymore. The wierd part is that it seems that if I play an offline game the Wi-Fi stays ok, but if I play an offline game AND have some Youtube opened it goes to shit again.

If the Wi-Fi dies and I try to connect to it again it reads "unable to connect to this network". If I turn off the Wi-Fi at this point, when I turn it back on, no Wi-Fi is pressnt in the list. At this point again, the Wi-Fi is missing from the list of network adapters and even device manager.

The way it is solved on the moment is with a restart, if that doesn't work maybe the 2 or the third will. But if the restarts don't work I try a shutdown for 3 mins. And when doesn't work either I leave it for the night.

As fixes, I tried to update the driver, didn't work, to stop the laptop from shutting down the Wi-Fi when there isn't enough power, didn't work, to stop IPv6 and some more things.  Nothing worked on the long run(more than 2 days)

I also opened the laptop and made sure the Wi-Fi plaque is connected properly to the motherboard

Please help me understand what is going on and how do I fix it

Comment: Based on your post, I might be inclined to try the following:  Remove the wireless card, start up, shut down, insert the wireless card and ensure clean connection and that antennae are properly attached.  Now start up and test.

Comment: Is there plenty of ventilation for the laptop (i.e. the vent slots are not covered) so that the Wi-Fi card has the best chance of not overheating?

Comment: You might also try a WiFi USB adapter, which could have better cooling, being outside the PC case.

Comment: @AndrewMorton not much, the laptop has a good ventilation, as far as the laptop goes, the wifi plaque is under the main SDD, so I guess that might be  problem

Comment: @John I will try and get back to you

Comment: "it is solved on the moment is with a restart, if that doesn't work maybe the 2 or the third will" That sounds like it is a problem with a broken WiFi card that gets only present if it gets warm. You might want to replace it. You can usually get them on eBay for under 20 bucks.

Comment: If you do replace the Wi-Fi card, make sure to get one with the same slots on the edge of the card where it goes into the socket on the motherboard, and you might want to download the manufacturer's drivers for the card before installing it if you don't have a wired network connection to the laptop available.

Comment: @John , thanks man, that seems to have done the trick

Comment: I posted an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your post, I might be inclined to try fully reinstalling the Wireless card.

Remove the wireless card, start up, and shut down.

Now insert the wireless card and ensure clean connection and that antennae are properly attached.

Now start up and test.

This procedure has worked for me, and the Author has reported this process worked for them as well.

Comment: this done it, after some tests and a day of full use the problem seems to have been solved. Thank you again John:D.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting.

Simplistic diagnosis would be:

- Does it do the same things on multiple wifi networks?

  - low probability: Even when one has WPA2 and other is purely open/public?
- Does using the built-in Ethernet jack (if available) give the same problem?
- Does using a USB Wifi dongle/adapater give the same problem?
- Is it related to heat?  I.e. if you shut down, let the laptop cool, and then spin up and start transferring exactly the same amount of data, does it die at the same time as if you shut down, let it cool, then boot up and run Prime95 for five minutes before you start transferring data?

  - or just try cranking up internal fans and putting it on another fan/AC vent or something.
- Does it do the same with a Live CD/USB boot, such as a Live Ubuntu test?  This eliminates your OS and drivers from consideration.